# JavaFX y getStyleClass

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-css

Tengo un problema al respecto del titulo. A nivel de código tengo claro el cómo obtener el nombre del StyleClass de un archivo fxml con la línea `this.getSkinnable().getStyleClass()` pero a partir de aquí, con el valor que me devuelve ¿Cómo puedo obtener el valor del styleClass a partir del nombre que me devuelve la línea de código aportada?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Leíste la documentación o algún [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/style_css.htm)? ¿Cuál es tu problema concretamente o qué no entiendes de lo que has leído?

Comment: He estado leyendo y no comprendo cómo obtener el valor del css en java a partir del nombre del StyleClass que obtengo a partir de la línea de código que puse

Comment: Está claramente explicado en los ejemplos. Si observas [este](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/style_css.htm#CHDCEIJA) o cualquier otro, verás que en la hoja de estilo hay declarada una clase llamada `.grid`, y en el código Java usarías `getStyleClass().add("grid")` si quieres aplicar ese estilo a algún elemento. Sea como sea, si no logras resolverlo, pon un ejemplo de tu CSS y del código Java donde intentas obtenerlo  y usarlo.

Comment: Ya lo he conseguido, era una tontería al final. Estaba llamando al estilo pero no lo estaba aplicando al componente correcto. Cosas de primerizos con el front. ¡Gracias por todo!

Comment: Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. Si hay algún otro error futuro se agradece que nos compartas el código específico donde el problema ocurre. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

si lo que buscas es cambiar el estilo de forma dinamica. Mi sugerencia es hacer un archivo .css y colocar todos los estilos alli y entonces aplicarlo al elmento a traves de condicionales que tu estableceras para que este sea aplicado al nodo.

```
private void clasificacionDelMaterial(){

    switch (tipoMaterial.getClasificacionMaterialidClasificacionMaterial().getNombre()) {
        case "Materia Prima":
            //contenedor.getStyleClass().add("mainFxmlClass1");
            contenedor.setStyle("-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(242,246,248,0.8) 0%, rgba(216,225,231,0.8) 50%, rgba(181,198,208,0.8) 51%, rgba(224,239,249,0.8) 100%);");
            
            break;
        case "Bases":
            //contenedor.getStyleClass().add("mainFxmlClass2");
            contenedor.setStyle("-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(238,234,242,0.8) 0%, rgba(222,208,224,0.8) 50%, rgba(207,182,204,0.8) 51%, rgba(234,223,245,0.8) 100%);");
           
            break;
        case "Productos":
            //contenedor.getStyleClass().add("mainFxmlClass3");
            contenedor.setStyle("-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(235,234,228,0.8) 0%, rgba(221,222,206,0.8) 50%, rgba(198,199,173,0.8) 51%, rgba(241,242,217,0.8) 100%);");
           
            break;
        case "Muestra/Contratipo":
            contenedor.setStyle("-fx-background-color:  linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(250,187,187,0.2) 0%, rgba(250,192,77,0.3) 50%, rgba(247,177,0,0.3) 51%, rgba(250,183,147,0.2) 100%);");
            break;
        default:
            contenedor.setStyle("-fx-background-color: silver;");
            break;
    }
}
```

archivo CSS

```
.mainFxmlClass {
    -fx-background-color: silver;
}
.mainFxmlClass1 {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(242,246,248,1) 0%, rgba(216,225,231,1) 50%, rgba(181,198,208,1) 51%, rgba(224,239,249,1) 100%);
}
.mainFxmlClass2 {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(238,234,242,1) 0%, rgba(222,208,224,1) 50%, rgba(207,182,204,1) 51%, rgba(234,223,245,1) 100%);
}

.mainFxmlClass3 {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(235,234,228,1) 0%, rgba(221,222,206,1) 50%, rgba(198,199,173,1) 51%, rgba(241,242,217,1) 100%);
}
```

en el ejemplo podras ver como colocar directamente el estilo y tambien como buscarlo del archivo css. Pero el metodo mescla ambas tecnicas para que tengas un ejemplo completo